# Textmate - indent no longer working for shortcut Cmd + ]

Tags: textmate

Recently the Textmate shortcuts `Cmd + [` and `Cmd + ]` for indent and outdent respectively stopped work.  When I trigger them now I just hear the warning bell.

I realise I can use `Alt + Tab` and `Alt + Shift + Tab` but I prefer the other shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

I had a bundle called zencode that commandeered the command-[ shortcut. I removed that bundle from the bundle list and I'm indenting again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the same problem and it was indeed this "zen-coding" bundle. If it's helpful to anyone, it's this bundle we're talking about: https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of preferences set...

Move `~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.textmate.plist` to someplace else and restart Textmate with all settings now at their defaults.

If you do have lots of preferences set (check by doing the above and seeing if it feels awful!) do as above and then compare the newly generated preferences file to your original (may require saving as XML with Property List Editor).